# how to you stop a worker dyno in heroku

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-cli, dyno

suppose I am running a worker `dyno` with following python code in heroku

```
import time
time.sleep(60*60)
exit()
```

I want to stop the worker completely, this code ends the program, but it starts again having the same effect as `heroku ps:restart worker` what should I write in the code to have the same effect as heroku `ps:scale worker=0`, is this possible ? If not what are my alternatives ?

Answer (score 2):

The worker processes defined in your `Procfile` should be always-on workers, same as the web-processes you define in there.

For one-off tasks that exit afterwards you can use a [one-off worker dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos). You can also easily define them in the [Heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler).